# Vuejs getting the element that is being called by an event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, vue.js

I have multiple list items that I want to toggle active classes on when they are being clicked on.

```
<ul class="list-body">
    <li v-on="click: setFilter('style', 'pils')" v-class="active: isActive">Pils</li>
    <li>Dubbel</li>
    <li>Tripel</li>
    <li v-on="click: setFilter('style', 'Quadrupel')">Quadrupel</li>
    <li>Wit</li>
</ul>
```

I already have a `setFilter` click function where I can add extra functionality to activate the class `onClick`.

```
setFilter: function(facet, value) {
    // Facet for style of beer(search filter)
    this.helper.addDisjunctiveFacetRefinement(facet, value).search();
},
```

My question is how can select the specific `li` element that was clicked on and called the with `setFilter` method?

I want to set a variable for the active class `false` or `true` for each single `li` element that has been clicked (or not clicked).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can directly pass the event and the events target in your function.
The target is the element you clicked on.

HTML:

```
<ul id="demo">
    <li v-on="click: onClick">Trigger a handler</li>
    <li v-on="click: n++">Trigger an expression</li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
var vue = new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data: {},
  methods: {
    onClick: function (e) {
      var clickedElement = e.target;
    }
  }
})
```

With your element you can do what you want.
For example, if you use jQuery:

```
$(clickedElement).siblings().removeClass('active');
$(clickedElement).addClass('active');
```

Comment: Just a quick question in my example I use this:

click: setFilter('style', 'pils')

Because I pass arguments the event handler doesn't work. How do I make it work like a function with arguments do I pass the event as an argument somehow?

Comment: Do not try do pass the element itself and the arguments.
You could call the setFilter from your onClick-Method and analyze your clicked element there.

Comment: This seems not to work in Vue 2.0. I tried to use *v-on:click="bla();"* like the docs suggest but then, while working, the event being sent in is undefined.

Comment: do you have "bla" defined?

Comment: @KonradViltersten, try removing the parentheses. And in the bla function the first parameter is the event. `bla(event){ ... }`

Comment: @TomásCot I got it working by *v-on:click="bla($event)"* but I'm guessing that there's no need to pass the event if it's being provided anyway. Thanks!

Comment: @KonradViltersten, it's not necessary but it might come in handy to know that when you also need to pass some other parameter.

Comment: e.target isn't cross browser no?

Comment: Looking at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target it seems cross-browser (depends on definition).

It should work in IE9 or newer (you can make it work in IE 7/8 with


`var target = e.target || e.srcElement;`


You maybe have to look at old safari versions.
But as per my definition it is cross-browser.

(Works in all browsers I care about)

Comment: I got to this solution (which worked) from a link that claimed it did not use jQuery.  In fact, Vue Bootstrap has an embedded copy of jQuery that allows the $(clickedElement) functionality to work.  Just clarifying.

Comment: Just FYI, if you were looking to target the actual element which has the listener attached, use `e.currentTarget` instead.