# How to obtain the id (or any other attribute) of the component clicked in Vue template?

Tags: javascript, action, vue.js, vuex

I have a setup like this. It's an element being clicked and invoking a method using it's specific string to be recognized. Of course, I'd prefer the ID to be provided so I won't have to maintain the redundant names.

```
<li id="donkey" v-on:click="clickaroo('donkey');">Donkey</li>
...
methods: {
  ...
  clickaroo: function(event) { console.log(event + " clicked"); }
}
```

When I went googlearching I've seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33173830/1525840) and [there](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/vue/getting-the-value-of-a-button-using-vuejs) that the syntax used was *v-on="click: clickaroo"* and not as shown [in the docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Method-Event-Handlers), i.e. *v-on:click="clickaroo"*. The former doesn't seem to work at all, let alone fetching me the right value.

I've also found [big nothing](https://forum-archive.vuejs.org/topic/541/how-to-get-info-on-the-element-that-triggers-an-event/5) and now I'm confused how to resolve the matter. Is it the proper way in Vue to provide the parameter like I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the element clicked from the current event.

The code would look something like this

```
<a v-on:click="myFunction($event, 'param')">Click me</a>

// in your component
methods: {
    myFunction: function(event, param) {
        console.log(event.target);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice. Any thoughts on the different syntax I linked it? It doesn't seem to work and I'm curious if it's just wrong or if it's Vue 1 spooking.

Comment: It looks like it's from an older version of vue 0.11 http://011.vuejs.org/guide/events.html

Comment: Oh, so it's actually Vue 0 spooking, hahaha.